# Eclipse won't start a new Android project anymore

Tags: android, eclipse, adk

A few weeks ago, I followed a tutorial to get Eclipse and the Android Development Kit up and running. I successfully built the test application and ran it on a virtual device.

Tonight I finally went back to do the next step in the tutorial, but when I went to start a new project there wasn't an option to start a new Android project. Even searching for it didn't produce anything. Window -> Preferences doesn't have an Android preferences dialog, either. The developer tools are still installed, though, according to Help -> Install New Software.

I'm using Eclipse Galileo 3.5.2 on Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick Meerkat. I just recently upgraded. I remember I had to install some additional packages to get Eclipse to run the Android stuff last time. I haven't uninstalled those, so I don't know what's causing the problem.

What's causing this problem, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Is it the same eclipse enviornment? You can have multiple different eclipse installations. Did you move the eclipse directory or the android sdk directory? We really don't have enough for us to help you. You can always reinstall the eclipse plugin from scratch

Comment: I didn't move anything, although I did upgrade Ubuntu ... I guess I'll just do a complete reinstall and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Re-check following things..........

1.) ADT is installed.
2.) Android SDK path is provided or not.

Comment: I verified that it's installed, and used the instructions at http://www.talkandroid.com/android-sdk-install-guide/ under Linux, adding export PATH=${PATH}:/home/feathertail/Android to my ~/.bashrc file. No dice. Also tried to do a complete reinstall, deleting the Android directory and using Synaptic to perform a complete removal of Eclipse before reinstalling it. I guess I'll try that again, and this time delete the .eclipse directory first if I can find it.

Comment: Okay, first off I was supposed to set the PATH to /Android/tools, but I've done that now. And deleting .eclipse and reinstalling everything worked ... I've successfully built and run a test app again. Sorry about that, I don't know why it went weird on me.

Comment: Pls mark this question as answered OR provide your own answer and mark it OR delete this question.